# storing new data of list into the text file

Tags: python

I'm having some problem. I want to do a loop of 38 times of transferring new list of data and store into notepad.

Example first loop: a =1, b=2 ,c=3; scanning []; ; scanning.append(a); scanning.append(b);scanning.append(c); my notepad will store in row of 1,2,3

Example second loop: a =2, b=4 ,c=5; scanning []; ; scanning.append(a); scanning.append(b);scanning.append(c); my txt will store 1,2,3 with next column of 2,4,5.

After 38 times, it will clear the txt.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH0hL.png)

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: are you use os module ??
you can create a text file using custom file format , note pad is a text editor program and not a file format to store your output.
you can use built-in function pickle or os module to create a .txt file and so on....

Comment: f = open("newfile", "w"); a =1, b=2 ,c=3; scanning = []; scanning.append(a); scanning.append(b); scanning.append(c); f = open("newfile", "w");  f.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), scanning))); f.close(); It saved in column instead of row. How I convert it into row?

Comment: You should update your post with the code, not a comment

Comment: ok. update the code in image

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("filename.txt","w") as fl:
    for i in range(0,38):
        #prepare ur list here 


        lst=str(i)+",2,3\n"#dummy list
        fl.write(lst)
    fl.close()

#to erase all content of file uncomment these line
#erase_fl=open("filename.txt","w")
#erase_fl.truncate() 
#erase_fl.close()
```